# Where can I find geomagnetic observations for the Indian Ocean region in 2017?

Tags: open-data, geomagnetism, satellites

I am looking for the geomagnetic data for the Indian Ocean region. The 3D data should correspond to longitude-latitude grids at hourly intervals.
The model data is easily available at NOAA but I need the observed values (satellite as well as surface observations) for the year 2017. I also checked the NOAA and USGS website but none of them are providing their data for the specific spatial domain.

Comment: Please edit your question to specify (1) whether you're looking for surface or satellite measurements, (2) what kind of spatial and temporal resolution you need, and (3) what kind of measurements you need (just intensity? just direction? full 3D vector?).

Answer (score 1):

For surface data, a good place to start is [Intermagnet](http://www.intermagnet.org/), a global network of geomagnetic observatories. Their [data download page](http://www.intermagnet.org/data-donnee/download-eng.php) lets you filter by time span and region, and sample rates down to the second are available for some observatories. The data are direct observations from individual observatories at fixed locations, and are not averaged over a region. (You mention in a comment that you couldn't find a station for ‘the northern equatorial part of the region near India’; for this region I'd suggest [Gan in the Maldives](http://www.intermagnet.org/imos/imos-list/imos-details-eng.php?iaga_code=GAN).)

For recent satellite data, the [Swarm mission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swarm_(spacecraft)) provides an excellent resource. [This page](https://earth.esa.int/web/guest/swarm/data-access) gives instructions on how to download their freely available data sets. Registration is required, but as far as I can tell it's free and available to anyone. They've also got an [excellent online visualization tool](https://earth.esa.int/web/guest/missions/esa-operational-eo-missions/swarm/news/-/article/visualisation-tool-for-swarm-data-now-open-for-users) which lets you explore their data interactively.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Intermagnet provides their data for the specific grid points. I am not sure whether it is averaged over a region or what, but no station was available for the northern equatorial part of the region near India. I shall check the satellite data and inform you soon.

Comment: @nshwal I've edited my answer to clarify that the station data isn't averaged, and to suggest an observatory in the region you mention.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay. I also checked the SWARM products but even after submission of the request, I couldn't get any data..:(